# <textarea> value, vs. innerHTML....in regards to PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-update, crud

I was trying to figure out a bug in my CRUD system with a

I want to propagate the text field with previous text for when a user needs to update the text area.

I'm using this code, setting the value to the text I wanted, but it won't work

```
<?php 
echo "<textarea name='text1' value= '".$row['text1']."' class='materialize-textarea'></textarea>";
echo "<label for='text1'>text notes</label>"; 
?>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The `for` attribute of a label needs to reference an **id** not a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo "<textarea name='text1'  class='materialize-textarea'>".$row['text1']."</textarea>";
echo "<label for='text1'>text notes</label>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing values in textarea doesnt work. There is no value attribute in textarea. You need to make it as innerHtml of textarea Try Below,

```
<?php 
    echo "<textarea name='text1' class='materialize-textarea'>'".$row['text1']."'</textarea>";
    echo "<label for='text1'>text notes</label>";
```

?>